# CLI: Editing binary strings

Tags: string, editors, utilities, binary, line-editor

There's a nice CLI `binutils` utility for interpreting binary files, and outputting legible strings, in a `cat`-like fashion. It's called `strings`.

If you try to `cat` a binary file, you'll see a bunch of garbled text and alien symbols. And probably have to `reset` your shell. Which is sometimes not even possible

Just like `cat`, basic usage is simply:

```
strings ./example.bin
```

Personally, for quick perusal, I like to:

```
strings -aws ' ' ./example.bin | fold -sw $COLUMNS ; echo
```

If you want to test it on a real file, you can try something in the `/bin` directory, like:

```
strings -aws ' ' /bin/true | fold -sw $COLUMNS ; echo
```

---

My question: Is there a similar, quick & easy method for editing these strings?

Comment: You might not want to edit binary files in a similar fashion. They will become garbled.

Comment: @tjt263. Yes, use a hex editor.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  `vim -b filename`.  The `-b` signifies binary file.  See man page for vim.

```
   -b          Binary mode.  A few options will be set that makes it
               possible to  edit  a  binary  or  executable file.
```

`bvi` also suitable.

```
$ bvi /bin/ls
00000000  7F 45 4C 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 3E 00 01 00 00 00 .ELF..............>.....
00000018  A0 49 40 00 00 00 00 00 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 38 E7 01 00 00 00 00 00 .I@.....@.......8.......
00000030  00 00 00 00 40 00 38 00 09 00 40 00 1D 00 1C 00 06 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 ....@.8...@.............
00000048  40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 00 40 00 00 00 00 00 40 00 40 00 00 00 00 00 @.......@.@.....@.@.....
00000060  F8 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 F8 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ........................
```

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this nice article about binary data manipulation:
[Manipulating Binary Data in Bash](http://www.linux-magazine.com/index.php/Issues/2018/210/Binary-Data-in-Bash/(tagID)/92)

It mostly explains a very handy tool called [`xxd`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xxd)

For example to dump a binary file in ASCII, you'll do:

```
xxd -b myfile.bin
```

To convert a short string, you could use the good old `bc`:

```
$ echo "obase=16; ibase=2; 1010" | bc
A
```

Another method to consider:

```
$ base64 < binary.file > text.file
```

> *ibase* and *obase* define the conversion base for input and output numbers. The default for both input and output is base 10.

Comment: I tried to convert my answer to a comment with no luck!